# how to solve error in docker-compose?

Tags: docker

```
version: '2'
services:
app:
build: app
proxy:
build: proxy
ports: 
- "80:80"
```

i get error ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service must be a mapping, not a NoneType.

Comment: Is that the entire compose yml file?

Comment: yeah it was just identation though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the lack of proper indentation.  Try with this one:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: app
  proxy:
    build: proxy
    ports: 
      - "80:80"
```

Comment: i had it like that before and it didn't work, weird...  thank you though

Comment: Did you try with the latest version of Docker Compose?

Comment: yeah i meant to say it worked but now i get this

proxy_1  | 2017/05/11 03:47:29 [emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "Server" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:1
proxy_1  | nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "Server" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:1
documentos_proxy_1 exited with code 1

Comment: The directive must be `server`, in lowercase.

Comment: it says i need more reputation for that